# Regex returning only first match?

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

I have a text file containing a lot of rows, I'm filtering them to find the content I need, like:

```
HBIJB LX 0359 25Aug14 07:37
```

This is my Regular Expression:

```
/(?:(HB...)\s(LX|WK)\s((?:[0-9]){1,4})\s((?:[0-9]){2}(?:[A-Z,a-z]){3}(?:[0-9]){2})\s((?:[0-9]){2}:(?:[0-9]){2}))/g
```

My problem is that it's returning only the first match in the file:

```
[ 
  'HBIJB LX 0359 25Aug14 07:37',
  'HBIJB',
  'LX',
  '0359',
  '25Aug14',
  '07:37',
  index: 323,
  input: /* Omitted */
]
```

The response is perfect, but why am I getting only the first match, even if I used the global `/g` flag?

**Edit:**

I'm using NodeJs, and the script is nothing fancy:

```
var regex = /(?:(HB...)\s(LX|WK)\s((?:[0-9]){1,4})\s((?:[0-9]){2}(?:[A-Z,a-z]){3}(?:[0-9]){2})\s((?:[0-9]){2}:(?:[0-9]){2}))/g
console.log(regex.exec(data));
```

**Edit 2:**

Here an extrapolation of the content I need to filter.

```
Lorem Ipsum Ø HBIJB LX 0359 25Aug14 07:37 HBIPV LX 2092 25Aug14 09:09
Lorem Ø HBIJB LX 1404 25Aug14 09:59 HBIJB LX 1405 25Aug14 10:53
```

Comment: You are probably using it wrong. What language are you using? What is the code that does the matching?

Comment: What language? And `{1}` may be omitted, also non capturing groups like `(?:\s)` may be abbreviated to `\s`.

Comment: @M42 Thanks, I will do the improvements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works fine for me,

```
> var s = "Lorem Ipsum Ø HBIJB LX 0359 25Aug14 07:37 HBIPV LX 2092 25Aug14 09:09\nLorem Ø HBIJB LX 1404 25Aug14 09:59 HBIJB LX 1405 25Aug14 10:53";
undefined
> console.log(s)
Lorem Ipsum Ø HBIJB LX 0359 25Aug14 07:37 HBIPV LX 2092 25Aug14 09:09
Lorem Ø HBIJB LX 1404 25Aug14 09:59 HBIJB LX 1405 25Aug14 10:53
undefined
> m = s.match((?:(HB...)\s(LX|WK)\s((?:[0-9]){1,4})\s((?:[0-9]){2}(?:[A-Z,a-z]){3}(?:[0-9]){2})\s((?:[0-9]){2}:(?:[0-9]){2})))
> m = s.match(/(?:(HB...)\s(LX|WK)\s((?:[0-9]){1,4})\s((?:[0-9]){2}(?:[A-Z,a-z]){3}(?:[0-9]){2})\s((?:[0-9]){2}:(?:[0-9]){2}))/g);
[ 'HBIJB LX 0359 25Aug14 07:37',
  'HBIPV LX 2092 25Aug14 09:09',
  'HBIJB LX 1404 25Aug14 09:59',
  'HBIJB LX 1405 25Aug14 10:53' ]
```

Comment: Using `match` instead of `exec` it works also for me! But I can't understand why, even if I now read the documentation on MDN

Comment: Added an answer to better document the solution to my problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is a clarification and expansion of the **correct** answer provided by **Avinash Raj**.

The problem is that I'm using `RegExp.prototype.exec()` but for what I intend to do, I need to use `String.prototype.match()` first:

```
var values = "Lorem Ipsum Ø HBIJB LX 0359 25Aug14 07:37 HBIPV LX 2092 25Aug14 09:09\nLorem Ø HBIJB LX 1404 25Aug14 09:59 HBIJB LX 1405 25Aug14 10:53";
values.match(/(?:(HB...)\s(LX|WK)\s((?:[0-9]){1,4})\s((?:[0-9]){2}(?:[A-Z,a-z]){3}(?:[0-9]){2})\s((?:[0-9]){2}:(?:[0-9]){2}))/g);

values.forEach(function(row) {
  var regex = /(?:(HB...)\s(LX|WK)\s((?:[0-9]){1,4})\s((?:[0-9]){2}(?:[A-Z,a-z]){3}(?:[0-9]){2})\s((?:[0-9]){2}:(?:[0-9]){2}))/g;
  var data = regex.exec(row));
}
```

This is because `String.prototype.match()` is returning an array containing every string matching the given RegExp, whereas `RegExp.prototype.exec()` is returning an array containing the groups matched by the given RegExp, if there is more than a string matching, only the first one is returned.